# How to stringify a whole Javascript Object including __proto__ properties?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, so far I couldn't find the same question.

I have an Object with various methods in my `__proto__` member.
Let's call the type of this object `myObjectType`.

Later on I have to do a `JSON.stringify(myObjectType)`. The problem is that then when I build my object from the previous obtained JSON string the type of my Object is plain `Object`, I lost all the methods I had.

Does any one see why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standardized way of incorporating functions into JSON data. You can do something *yourself* — that is, write your own JSON serializer that incorporates functions according to some convention — but with straight standard JSON you get numbers, strings, booleans, and `null`, plus of course objects with named properties and arrays. No functions, just data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779249/how-to-stringify-inherited-objects-to-json

Answer (score 4):

search [google](http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript%20oject%20serialization#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=kzN&channel=cs&sa=X&ei=ccC2TbLMOY7qrQfb0eX_Cg&ved=0CBwQvwUoAQ&q=javascript%20object%20serialization&spell=1&fp=7151c1ee4303777a&biw=1024&bih=516) for javascript object serialization.

[GSerializer library](http://www.onegeek.com.au/projects/javascript-serialization)

Comment: Vm hmm by my effigy.ie.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend Douglas Crockford's libraries:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js