# Why angular doesn't display prototypical object in view?

Tags: angularjs

I have been Googling a lot to find answer for this but I wasn't able to do so.
I found this issue, and I don't know what causes it. I know that workarounds exist, but I would like to know why this is happening.

Why am I not able to display prototypical objects in view from `{{object}}` expression?

By inspecting $scope i know that values are there, but i am not able to display them in JSON format on view.

Here is live example I made that tells everything.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sm3LXLxbwQ7I5vo2fjbN?p=preview

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Live example updated, because previous link was broken!

2nd UPDATE:

Answers about Angular function witch ignores object properties with names starting with $ are completely right and i understand those, but yesterday i ran into same problem with Geolocation.
Geolocation is not an Angular object, and it doesn't contain $ sign, but it also doesn't work.
Please check new updated plnkr! And Thanks for effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your plunkr is related to a problem displaying prototypical objects, but more about displaying $location particularly.

After some debugging, it turns out that angular internally calls

> angular.toJson($location)

And that call returns an empty object instead of the stringified version of the object. If you use JSON.stringify (which is used internally  by angular, but with a replacer function that ignores variable names that start with '$' )

I modified your plunkr to manually stringify $location instead of calling angular.toJson.

Here's the modified plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RszniTwU251lcXvJ3cFT?p=preview

Note how I added the following line in the controller:

```
 $scope.stringifiedLocation = JSON.stringify($location);
```

And this line in the view:

```
 <p>Stringified version ($scope.stringifiedLocation): {{stringifiedLocation}}</p>
```

Which produces the following output:

> Stringified version ($scope.stringifiedLocation):
>   {"$$protocol":"http","$$host":"run.plnkr.co","$$port":80,"$$path":"","$$search":{},"$$hash":"","$$url":"","$$absUrl":"http://run.plnkr.co/8NE1mySlQzBI1dLz/","$$state":null}

I also added a prototype object to try to answer the original question. JSON.stringify does not preserve any of the prototype properties of the object. [More info in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779249/how-to-stringify-inherited-objects-to-json)

**EDIT to address your 2nd edit**

It looks like objects such as Geolocation and File (and many others), cannot properly be stringified even with [flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779466). Here's some background as to why, taken from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10524):

> File (and many others) are what used to be called host objects, parts of the platform mainly implemented in C++ --- they have JS bindings automatically generated from IDL files, like this https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/fileapi/File.idl
>
> Those properties are defined as accessors, and they'll try to invoke
>   the accessors implemented in C++ --- the problem is that
>   Object.create(File.prototype) isn't going to construct the C++ backend
>   for this class, thus we don't really have these accessors, thus JSC
>   decides to throw here (see
>   https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/bindings/scripts/CodeGeneratorJS.pm#L2206-L2211
>   --- if it can't cast to the host object, it's gonna throw.

Comment: Please check 2nd update, i also updated plnkr, and included your PrototypicalObject witch works well, but i am confused now...

Comment: I'm still getting the same plunkr.

Comment: Hmm, caching should not be issue, but when i open link from my question, i get newest version...

Comment: OK, looks like I finally have a proper answer to your second edit, take a look at my edit please.

Comment: Great! That's the right answer. Actually my problem had two different sources, and both of them are explained here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OhuyBu1xiXCHndlEbn4J?p=preview).

Your code doesn't show anything, because the filter doesn't show any properties starting with `$`. From [AngularJS 1.4.3 source code Line 1176](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js):

```
function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
  var val = value;

  if (typeof key === 'string' && key.charAt(0) === '$' && key.charAt(1) === '$') {
    val = undefined;
  } else if (isWindow(value)) {
    val = '$WINDOW';
  } else if (value &&  document === value) {
    val = '$DOCUMENT';
  } else if (isScope(value)) {
    val = '$SCOPE';
  }

  return val;
}
```

So, if you assign some property to `$location`, say `$location.myData = 'Joy';`, this piece of data is shown correctly.

Well, if you assign the scope `$scope.myScope = $scope;` and show it `{{ myScope | json }}`, you will get plain string `$SCOPE`.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't complete by the time you answered. Now, I've updated live example. I also tried adding json filter, but it still shows empty object despite the fact that object is not empty.

Comment: please check 2nd update, i also updated plnkr. Thanks!

Comment: I added `console.log('Getting current position');` to the function `getCurrentPosition`, it is not even printed out. This function is not called correctly on my machine. I think it is another story other than `show Angular objects on view`.