# nested object JSON sorting JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I'm not sure I am asking the right question or not.
I get a JSON response like this from my server request

```
{
"20150917":
     {
         "Daily01sec":
            {
                "TG01152600000": "\/20150917\/Daily01sec\/TG0115260.bin",
                "TG01152600600": "\/20150917\/Daily01sec\/TG0115260.bin",
            }
        },
"201510":
        {
            "05":
            {
                "Daily01sec":
                {
                    "TG01152780600": "\/201510\/05\/Daily01sec\/TG01152780600.bin",                       
                }
            }
        },
"201509":
        {
            "05":
            {
                "Daily01sec":
                {
                    "TG01152780600": "\/201510\/05\/Daily01sec\/TG01152780600.bin",                       
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I want to count all folders and sort them.

I want to get sorted like this for master folders:

```
"201509"
"201510"
"20150817"
```

please check the example data at here
http://jsfiddle.net/ebrahimmm/ncykb0qq/1/

here is the code receiving via $http at angularJS

```
angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('cntl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://'+'server' + "/getdatalogtree").
    then(
       function (response) {
        var data=response.data;
       //here i need sorting     
       },function(response){
    });
});
```

I also want to put each mast folders and its content to be an element of an array.

Comment: Also, post the code you've tried already. Don't expect SO users to do all the work for you.

Comment: I should say that for example "20150917" is a folder name

Comment: Here's how to do it. Assign the JSON to variable, use for..in to get all property names and put them in an array, then sort the array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ebrahimmm/ncykb0qq/1/

Comment: Don't just post a fiddle. Fiddles go away. Post the code here.

Comment: I found a possible answer for iterating the objects here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779249/how-to-stringify-inherited-objects-to-json

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys(Your_JSON_Response)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method, to get array of keys.
And then [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit ::** One-Liner

This should do the job :

```
function foo(dataString) {
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(dataString)).map(parseFloat).sort(function(a,b) {return a[0]-b[0]}).map(String); //datastring -> Your JSON string which you get from the server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one line will do this job:

```
function foo(dataString) {
    return Object.keys(dataString).sort();}
```