# json.stringify of web audio nodes return empty

Tags: json, audio, stringify

Is there a way to stringify a web audio node object (such as `gain,biquadfilter`) to save/restore its settings?

```
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
var str = JSON.stringify( gainNode );
console.log( str );
```

sadly str returns "{}"

Comment: What do you understand by "Stringify audio node object" ? What kind of result do you expect if not `{}` ? (I'm not specialist in this domain, but may help)

Comment: I think he refers to something that casts the object state into a unique string, like Java's toString() method.

Comment: i'd expect something like:     <pre>{gain: AudioParam, context: AudioContext, numberOfInputs: 1, numberOfOutputs: 1, channelCount: 2, …}</pre>

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` only includes the object's own properties, and not properties inherited from the prototype chain. See [How to stringify inherited objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779249/how-to-stringify-inherited-objects-to-json) for more details.

One way to print all properties, including inherited ones:

```
function flatten(obj) {
    var ret = {};
    for (var i in obj) {
        ret[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return ret;
}

var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
var str = JSON.stringify(flatten(gainNode));
console.log(str);
```

While `JSON.stringify()` only includes own properties, the `for (var i in obj)` syntax iterates over all properties, including inherited ones (except non-enumerable properties, but a `GainNode` doesn't have those).