# How convert javascript _proto_ object to json

Tags: javascript

How can we convert javascript `__proto__` object to a json string output

```js
this.products.forEach(function(element, index) {
  productsInfo.push(productsFormItems[index].myFunction());
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(productsInfo));

myFunction() {
  let result = Object.create({
    ProductName: { value: this.formData.ProductName },
    Address: { value: this.formData.Address }
  });
  return result;
}
```

See the sample example below:

[image]

Required json format:

```
"productInfo":[
      {
         "ProductName":"Testdata"
         "Address":"TestValue"
      }
  ]
  [
      {
         "ProductName":"Testdata"
         "Address":"TestValue"
      }
  ]
```

Comment: I may be missing something but why do you use `Object.create`? It seems like you always get a new thing anyway, so you can just produce the object. I can't see the reason to play with prototypes here.

Comment: Also, your required format doesn't match what you produce in `.myFunction()`. It's easier to just produce arrays from that method.

Comment: I understood btw I am trying to create a new object with an existing object . The new object doesn't need all the attributes in the existing object. I am not pretty sure what to use thats why  used  Object.create({

Comment: It's a bit unclear why `Object.create()` is required. But, for stringifying inherited properties, you can use this: [How to stringify inherited objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779249)

Comment: If you want to produce a new object, literally just delete `Object.create` and you are done. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) will make a new object and assign the parameter you pass in as the *prototype*. So, it's a "create object from this other object". Your literal inside the brackets is already creating a new object, seems you want to just use that.

Comment: @VLAZ You are right and thanks . I have removed the Object.create and its working now.