# Why can't specify the constructor's prototype inside that constructor? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function Graph() {
      this.vertices = [];
      this.edges = [];
      Graph.prototype = {
            x : 0,
            y : 0
      };
};
console.log(Graph.prototype);
var g = new Graph();
console.log(g.x);
console.log(g.y);
```

Inside the constructor **Graph**, which is a toy exmaple, I try to assign an object to its prototype.

```
function Graph() {
      this.vertices = [];
      this.edges = [];
      Graph.prototype = {
            x : 0,
            y : 0
      };
}
```

When I look at Graph.prototype using:

```
console.log(Graph.prototype);
```

I find that Graph.prototype is still the default prototype. I didn't make any change to it.
Why can't I specify the constructor's prototype inside that constructor? Can someone tell me the real reason behind it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks to be assigned properly to me, both when logging at the end of the constructor and after creating an instance, can you show where you're doing the `console.log` in relation to the other code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Presumably the OP doesn't invoke the `new Graph` constructor and expects `Graph.prototype` to be updated _statically_? (i.e. after the JavaScript parser runs, without any code execution).

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm doing the `console.log` in the same level of the definition of Graph. By the way, if you create an instance named _g_ of Graph, you'll find _g.x_ and _g.y_ are undefined. That's the reason why I think I didn't make any change to Graph's prototype.

Comment: You have to use `this.constructor.prototype` within a constructor. Of course, you would have a context issue with that Object then. Improper use of `prototype`.

Comment: @Jackie I don't see `typeof g.x === 'undefined'` when I try. I think you're still missing something. Can you please post a minimal reliable reproduction from JSFiddle or a StackOverflow snippet?

Comment: @StackSlave  `this.constructor.prototype` is the same reference as `Graph.prototype` inside the constructor. However a type's prototype probably should never be updated from inside the type's constructor because it complicates reasoning about types.

Comment: This seems like a misuse of the prototype since the prototype is shared among ALL instances, therefore better solutions would either assign static data to the prototype just once outside the constructor or just initialize instance variables inside the constructor. There is no reason for setting new properties on the prototype inside the constructor. It's either just wrong or an inefficient place to do it.

Comment: @Dai I just added a code snippet. That's the whole context of my question. By the way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: When called as a constructor, the new instance is created and assigned a `[[Prototype]]` before code in the constructor body is executed. So by the time a new object is assigned to the constructor's  prototype, the instance already has the old one.

Answer (score 3):

### Background

I assume that you're calling `console.log(Graph.prototype);` **before** running the `Graph` constructor.

Remember that JavaScript's formal type-system for `object` values uses mutable prototypes as a way of implementing object-inheritance, and those `prototype` object references can also be swapped-out entirely and redefined at runtime even after object values using that prototype already exist, which makes it much harder to reason about a JavaScript program's type-safety (for this reason TypeScript still cannot represent every valid JavaScript program, as of early 2020).

For example, consider:

```
// 1. Declare `Foo` constructor.
function Foo() {
    this.bar = 123;
}
// 2. Extend the prototype:
Foo.prototype.baz = 456;

// 3. Create a new instance of Foo:
const foo1 = new Foo();
console.log( "foo1.baz == %o", foo1.baz ); // "456"

// 4. Change the prototype:
delete Foo.prototype.baz;
Foo.prototype.qux = "abc";

// 5. Create a second new instance of Foo:
const foo2 = new Foo();
console.log( "foo2.qux == %o", foo2.qux ); // "abc"

// 6. Because Foo's prototype is changed, `foo1.baz` is no-longer valid:
console.log( "foo1.baz == %o", foo1.baz ); // "undefined"
```

So the *formal-type* of `foo1` (i.e. the set of properties of `foo1`) is entirely up-in-the-air - which is why it's a good idea to never redefine a `prototype` in JavaScript before any objects using that prototype are created.

### The Answer

With that background out of the way...

> "Why can't I specify the constructor's prototype inside that constructor? Can someone tell me the real reason behind it?"

You technically *can*, it just won't work the way you want it to:

- The `Foo.prototype` (or `Graph.prototype` in your case) would only be set *when and only when* the first `new Foo()` call is made.
- The `Foo.prototype` object would be *reupdated* on *every* Constructor call.

  - This would be a bad thing: I'm unsure if JavaScript engines would treat the same lexical object-literal as the same instance of an object or would create a *new* object from the object-literal - either way, it makes your program much harder to reason about.

If you want to succinctly define the prototype in the same "place" in your project's codebase then just define it immediately after the Constructor function definition, this also means that `Graph.prototype` *will* be updated as-expected without needing to actually create any `new Graph` objects.

So this is what you're currently doing:

```
function Graph() {
    this.vertices = [];
    this.edges    = [];
    Graph.prototype = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
}

console.log( Graph.prototype ); // "{}" or "{constructor: f}"
```

But if you update the prototype immediately after defining the constructor it will work as-intended:

```
function Graph() {
      this.vertices = [];
      this.edges    = [];
}
Graph.prototype = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

console.log( Graph.prototype ); // "{x: 0, y: 0}"
```

### Regarding `this.constructor`, `this.constructor.prototype`, and `Graph.prototype`.

Inside a constructor function:

- `this` refers to the newly created object-instance.
- `this.constructor` refers to the constructor function (`function TypeName()`).
- `this.prototype` is undefined as `prototype` is only defined on (constructor) functions.
- `TypeName.prototype`:

  - By default this is an object with this definition:

    ```
    { constructor: f } // where `f` is `function TypeName`.
    ```
  - If `TypeName.prototype` is redefined anywhere (even inside the constructor) then it will be equal to that redefinition **but only after** the code that performs the redefinition actually executes (so not when the JavaScript code is merely loaded and parsed).
- `this.constructor.prototype` also refers to `TypeName.prototype` (i.e. `TypeName.prototype === this.constructor.prototype`):

### BTW, it breaks JSON:

Note that you probably *don't* want to do this anyway because object properties inherited from a `prototype` are not considered "own" properties and so are excluded from `JSON.stringify` output, e.g.:

```
var g    = new Graph();
var json = JSON.stringify( g );
console.log( json ); // "{"vertices":[],"edges":[]}"
```

[Fortunately there's a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779249/how-to-stringify-inherited-objects-to-json) you can use for *serialization* (but implementing a `prototype`-aware `JSON.parse` is an exercise for the reader):

```
function JSON_stringify_for_prototypes( obj ) {
    const flat = Object.create( obj );
    for( const key in flat ) { // `for( x in y )` includes non-"own" properties.
        flat[key] = flat[key]; // This looks silly, but this actually causes each property to be marked as "own" in `flat`.
    }

    return JSON.stringify( flat );
}
```

Comment: Very well explained and a very good point about breaking JSON.  I do wonder if the OP really wants static properties that are the same for all object.  That seems unlikely.  It seems more likely that they should just initialize `this.x = 0` and `this.y = 0` in the constructor and make them real properties not shared static properties.

Comment: Re "*prototype-based type-system*". Javascript has prototype based inheritance, type is a different thing altogether. Re: "*… allows types to be dynamically defined and redefined…*" assuming "types" means prototype, then yes, but it's considered a bad idea to change the prototype object itself once instances have been created.

Comment: @RobG I meant "type" as in the same sense as in "Hindley-Miller's Type System" (but I'm not otherwise referencing Hindley-Miller's algorithm as that doesn't apply in this case). Not about ECMAScript's `typeof` or prototypes specifically (i.e. looking at the general shape of a given object value, regardless of its inheritance, composition, or prototypes).

Comment: Sure, but Type is defined in ECMA-262 and the more generic "type" really applies to values (number, int, float, string, etc.) so somewhat confusing to use it in the context of class (or at least what other languages would call class). :-)

Comment: @RobG Right. I'm actually working on a somewhat academic type-system project right now so my mental-dictionary definition of "type" is far more abstract than I imagine most JavaScript users reading my answer might be - but I'm unsure of how I could reword it to be clearer and unambiguous to all levels: from beginners through to mathematics boffins who probably write down their grocery shopping-lists using formal group-theory set operations.

Comment: I would write it as "JavaScript's prototype-based *inheritance* allows *inherited properties* to be dynamically defined and redefined". I think your "type–safety" refers to mutability of the prototype from which an object inherits, that can be controlled using *Object.create* and *Object.defineProperty/Properties* rather than object literals. Anyway, as long as the reader gets the message I guess it's fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `Graph.prototype` instead of replacing it with a new object, and you need to `console.log(Graph.prototype)` *after* calling the constructor rather than before:

```js
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
  Graph.prototype.x = 0;
  Graph.prototype.y = 0;
};

var g = new Graph();

console.log(Graph.prototype);
console.log(g.x);
console.log(g.y);
```

But as others have said, because the prototype is shared by all instances of `Graph`, you probably don't actually want to do this. Without anymore context, it just seems like you want two more properties `x` and `y` for each instance:

```js
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
};

var g = new Graph();

console.log(g);
console.log(g.x);
console.log(g.y);
```

Comment: Why would you ever initialize the prototype inside constructor, every time that constructor is run?  If you want to initialize, it do it once outside the constructor since it's the same prototype every time the constructor runs.

Comment: @jfriend00 agreed, but perhaps this information that assigning to `Graph.prototype` rather than adding properties to it is useful for explaining to OP the behavior unexpected by them. Without anymore context, it's really unclear what it is they're trying to do at all, but without that context, this is what I thought would be the most helpful information for them.

Comment: @jfriend00 and who knows? Maybe they really do want shared properties that are reset every time a new instance is created. I'll let them figure that out though, because that's not what they've asked about.

Comment: Well, you've been around here long enough to know that people often ask for a solution that isn't the right solution to their problem.  There's a 99% chance that's what is happening here since a changing prototype is almost never what someone wants for a simple `x,y` coordinate.

Answer (score -5):

It seems to me like you are really just trying to create a method that sets static properties. Here's how you would go about attempting to replicate this in JavaScript:

```js
function Graph(){
  this.vertices = []; this.edges = [];
  this.staticXY = (x = 0, y = 0)=>{
    const p = this.constructor.prototype;
    p.x = x; p.y = y;
    return this;
  }
  if(this.x === undefined && this.y === undefined)this.staticXY();
}
const graph1 = new Graph;
graph1.staticXY(2, 8); graph1.x = 3; graph1.y = 1;
console.log(graph1.x, graph1.y); // static remains anyways
const graph2 = new Graph;
console.log(graph2.x, graph2.y);
```

Comment: If your comment is relevant to your answer, copy it into your answer.  Your answer should stand on its own.  What the OP is asking about seems like a misuse of the prototype since the prototype is shared among ALL instances, therefore better answers would either assign static data to the prototype outside the constructor or just initialize instance variables inside the constructor.  There is no reason for setting new properties on the prototype inside the constructor.  It's either just wrong or an inefficient place to do it.

Comment: Comments here are for adding commentary to answers and has nothing to do with your "free" donation of content (we all participate here for free).  Like many questions here on Stackoverflow, I think the OP is asking to do the wrong thing (without explaining why or what they're really trying to do).  You should not be assigning static properties in a constructor, ever.  Either assign them once outside the constructor (where all other things are put on the prototype) or put them on the class object where static data is usually put.   This answer isn't the right way to do what you're doing.

Comment: @Jackie after you ask some real experts, not the downvoters, please accept this as the answer. It'll teach the downvoters. Thanks!