# Why does JSON.stringify returns "{}"?

Tags: javascript, json

I have one prototype of this structure:

```
function MyObj() { }

MyObj.prototype = {
    prop1: {
        prop11: null,
        prop12: null,
        prop13: null,
    },
    prop2: {
        prop21: null,
        prop22: null,
        prop23: null,
    },
    prop3: {
        prop31: [],
        prop32: '',
        prop34: [],
    },
    prop4: {
        prop41: null,
    },
}
```

When I call `JSON.stringify(myObjInstance)`, I get `{}`, why?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369543/why-is-json-stringify-not-serializing-prototype-values. You can write your custom [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `prop1` through `prop4` are properties of the prototype and not of the instantiated object.

You can compare it to something like:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // add property to bag
    }
}
```

Only the properties of the object itself are used.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`JSON.stringify`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3) only includes an object's *own* properties (specifically, own *enumerable* properties), not properties an object inherits from its prototypes or any of its own properties that are non-enumerable.

So for example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/EPiSisEQ/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/EPiSisEQ/1/edit)

```
function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype.inherited = true;

var f = new Foo();
Object.defineProperty(f, "ownNonEnumerable", {
    value: true
});

f.ownEnumerable = true;

console.log(f.inherited);        // true
console.log(f.ownNonEnumerable); // true
console.log(f.ownEnumerable);    // true
console.log(JSON.stringify(f));  // {"ownEnumerable": true}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` will only include a property if it can be found with `hasOwnProperty`, and

```
new MyObj().hasOwnProperty("prop1") === false;
```

Try this instead:

```
JSON.stringify(MyObj.prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify(obj)` will output the properties that the object *itself* has, not its prototype. Its prototype is a different object.

What you're looking for would be something like this

```
JSON.stringify(MyObj.prototype)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, when I start working with JSON.stringify. In order to create a string the object you create needs to of typeof == object. Otherwise it won't work.

Try to alert the typeOf of MyObj. If it not Object that won't work.

```
MyObj = {
prop1: {
    prop11: null,
    prop12: null,
    prop13: null,
},
prop2: {
    prop21: null,
    prop22: null,
    prop23: null,
},
prop3: {
    prop31: [],
    prop32: '',
    prop34: [],
},
prop4: {
    prop41: null,
},
```

}