# Javascript JSON.stringify doesn't handle prototype correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

I've been initializing my reusable classes like this (constructor is usually a copy-constructor):

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.a = "1";
Foo.prototype.b = "2";
Foo.prototype.c = [];
var obj = new Foo();
obj.c.push("3");
```

but the JSON.stringify does not produce the expected result:

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

{}

The variables work as expected for everything else.
If toJSON is overridden, it works fine:

```
Foo.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    return {
        a: this.a,
        b: this.b,
        c: this.c
    };
};
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

{"a":"1","b":"2","c":["3"]}

It also works fine if the variables are defined inside the constructor:

```
function Alt() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = "2";
    this.c = [];
}
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

{"a":1,"b":"2","c":["3"]}

What's going on?

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FdzB6/

Comment: The JSON serializer only pays attention to properties directly on the objects being serialized ("own" properties).

Comment: @Pointy: But doesn't `Foo.prototype.a` add "own" properties?

Comment: enumerating the own properties for Foo shows a, b, c in the list

Comment: @RocketHazmat  Properties on the prototype are just properties on the prototype.

Comment: @MikeEmery for "Foo", the function?!?  No, the function "Foo" doesn't have those properties, and neither will an object created by calling `new Foo` - they'll be *readable* from the prototype via an instance, of course, but a `hasOwnProperty("a")` test will return `false`.

Comment: @Pointy: So, you're saying they exist further up the prototype chain, so they don't appear?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes; there's really no difference between a simple string or number-valued prototype property and a function property. The lookup process for a property reference is the same. I should add an answer I guess :)

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, it seems like you've hit the nail on the head with what's going on here :-)

Comment: For reference, here's how is implemented Crockford's stringify : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L326

Comment: Would you say initializing properties with prototype is a bad practice in general then?

Comment: @MikeEmery well, it depends on what you're trying to do. If the ability to serialize objects with JSON is really important, then yes I'd say it's a bad idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties on an object's prototype (that is, the prototype of its constructor) are *readable* via a reference to an the object:

```
function Constructor() { }
Constructor.prototype.a = "hello world";

var x = new Constructor();
alert(x.a); // "hello world"
```

However, those properties really are "stuck" on the prototype object:

```
alert(x.hasOwnProperty("a")); // false
```

The JSON serializer only pays attention to properties that directly appear on objects being processed. That's kind-of painful, but it makes a little sense if you think about the reverse process: you certainly don't want `JSON.parse()` to put properties back onto a prototype (which would be pretty tricky anyway).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - the bit about using JSON.parse later is especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

your answer lies [Why is JSON.stringify not serializing prototype values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369543/why-is-json-stringify-not-serializing-prototype-values)

JSON.stringify only does "own" properties.

In your first example:
prototype members are being set, and then calling `Stringify` on the object itself, which does not have its own properties.

In your second:
`this.a` will climb the chain until it finds the property

In the third:
You are setting properties directly on the object and not its prototype