# What is the common practice of solving JSON write\read problems for nested properties?

Tags: javascript, json

In my API I created the hierarhy of nesting through prototypes. It is convenient. But I see that `JSON.stringify` does not include the properties of prototypes...

How usualy solving the JSON write\read problem for such cases? What is the common practice of solving such problems?

```
let a = {x:0},

    b = Object.create(a, {
        y : { value: 0,
            enumerable: true
        }
    }),

    c = Object.create(b,{
        z:{
            value:0,
            enumerable:true
        }
    }),

    d = JSON.stringify(c);

console.log(d); // {"z":0}
```

Comment: It's because it only looks at "own" properties, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732299/javascript-json-stringify-doesnt-handle-prototype-correctly)

Comment: If you need to stringify all those properties use Object.assign instead and don't put them in prototype

Comment: In my API I created the hierarhy of nesting through prototypes. It is convenient. How usualy solving the JSON write\read problem for such cases? What is the common practice of solving such problems?