# Object.create(someObject) function does not inherit the properties

Tags: javascript

When an object is created using Object.create(someObject) method the properties of the original method is not derived by the created method. How to make it derive the existing properties.?

```
> a = {}

> a.p1 = '8'; // add a property to object

> b = Object.create(a);

> b // b does not inherit the property p1.
{}
```

To reproduce the bug use the node console as shown below:

```
$ node
> a = {}
{}
> a.p1 = 2;
2
> b = Object.create(a);
{}
> b
{}
> a
{ p1: 2 }
>
```

Comment: You are incorrect; object b will inherit p1. I can prove it my browser console; maybe your syntax was incorrect when you tried this out?

Comment: $ node
> a = {}
{}
> a.p1 = 2;
2
> b = Object.create(a);
{}
> b
{}
> a
{ p1: 2 }
>

Comment: Strange, I can reproduce the OP's problem.

Comment: @wumm - perhaps this is a node bug.

Comment: Looks like just a display thing. `b.p1` gives `2`.

Comment: @wumm i had updated my answer on how to reproduce in node console.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit Erm, yes? I said I *can* reproduce your problem.

Comment: @wumm sorry. I just did not look closely, just came to wrong conclusion as soon as i looked at the words "Strange" and "reproduce"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no bug all is working correctly. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified **prototype** object and properties.

The object is created with a prototype but prototypes are never shown in node (and in any browser console I know). You can see the prototype by using `b.__proto__`

[image]

Comment: Just curious. About like 5 minutes ago you had thought reproducing the problem was strange which means you were not aware of the answer. How did you manage to find the answer so fast.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit After trying it out in the node console I checked the MDN documentation to make sure I remembered correctly what Object.create does. And there I just realized that it creates an object from a prototype. So I tried displaying the prototype and indeed it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Prototype properties will not be a part of string representation printed to console.

You can verify that `b.p1` can indeed be called and the corresponding value is 2

You can also try printing `b.__proto__` which gives `{ p1: 2 }`

Comment: Yes. JSON.stringify does not serialize prototype properties - There is already a relevant SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369543/why-is-json-stringify-not-serializing-prototype-values The accepted answer has links to ES specs.